# Network Configuration Gone - Unable to Reset or Apply Netplan

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, netplan

I'm not sure what's going on or what happened. I run an Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS machine headless. It performed an update sometime overnight and when I logged in, it prompted me that it needed a reboot. So I did, however, it didn't appear to come back up.

After attaching a monitor to it, I discovered that it was running, but the network interface was not functional. Not even appearing actually, like it was just deleted or removed. I'll try to share as much information here, but I'm just not sure what could be wrong and I honestly don't know where else to look.

After trying everything below, I still have no internet connection. What's worse, after a reboot the only way to get an IP address on my LAN to allow an SSH is by using:

```
$ sudo ip link set enp3s0 down
$ sudo ip link set enp3s0 up
$ sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.150/24 dev enp3s0
```

```
$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 2c:56:dc:97:80:9f
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 ip=192.168.1.150 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea00fff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
```

```
$ sudo nano /etc/netplan/netcfg.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.150/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

After a reboot, the above `netplan` configuration remains, however, additional spacing is being added to some of the lines - causing it to fail.

```
$ ip a
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:56:dc:97:80:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.150/24 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:1970:4a26:8100:2e56:dcff:fe97:809f/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 86140sec preferred_lft 14140sec
```

```
$ ip route show
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-5c71e5479641 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.150
```

I am only able to get the `default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0` portion to appear after running `sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1`.

```
$ sudo netplan --debug try
DEBUG:enp3s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.150/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 1.1.1.1
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2

DEBUG:New interfaces: set()
** (generate:53716): DEBUG: 22:58:01.445: Processing input file /etc/netplan/netcfg.yaml..
** (generate:53716): DEBUG: 22:58:01.445: starting new processing pass
** (generate:53716): DEBUG: 22:58:01.446: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:53716): DEBUG: 22:58:01.446: enp3s0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:53716): DEBUG: 22:58:01.446: Configuration is valid
** (generate:53716): DEBUG: 22:58:01.446: Generating output files..

An error occurred: the configuration could not be generated

Reverting.
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, restarting networkd
DEBUG:enp3s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.150/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 1.1.1.1
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2

DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
DEBUG:enp3s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.150/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 1.1.1.1
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2

DEBUG:Link changes: {}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp3s0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-5c71e5479641
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for docker0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethf90fcb2
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth71540be
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth18e90b7
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vetheb58aaa
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth728e8e9
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth96def70
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vetha4b92ad
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethd43e21c
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethb777853
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth2b054d4
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth8f6354f
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethc69182e
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth9e52006
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth9b90b02
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth3f22dda
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethc39e6d3
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vetha38ae56
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethf68a144
DEBUG:enp3s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.150/24
      dhcp4: false
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 1.1.1.1
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

This is about all the information I have. I'm just not sure what went wrong, where, how, when.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *additional spacing is being added to some of the lines - causing it to fail.* -- Please file a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with the network being offline after an update on Ubuntu 20.x.

I found this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1922898

Here is how I was able to fix my Ubuntu 20.x servers:

1. Download latest `netplan.io_0.102`:

   ```
   cd /tmp 
   wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netplan.io/netplan.io_0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Run the following command as root:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i netplan.io_0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Confirm that both `netplan` and `libnetplan` are in sync:

   ```
   $ sudo dpkg -l | grep netpl
   libnetplan0:amd64                    0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.1          amd64        YAML network configuration abstraction runtime library
   netplan.io                           0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.1          amd64        YAML network configuration abstraction for various backends
   ```
4. Reboot.

Comment: Glorious! I was literally, just booting into a live USB to reinstall. Thanks for saving my life -- well, my time. +1

Comment: Glad to have helped.  This was quite annoying bug due to a missing installation dependency.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Cloud Users:** I suffered the same problem on three machines in the GCP. Since there is no way to transfer a file I can't implement the fix as provided by user15523715 directly. However I was able to implement it with the following modifications.

1. Create or go to an Ubuntu VM that is working in the GCP
2. Create a blank disk and attach.
   See: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk
3. SSH or Console into the VM and Format and Mount the disk.
   See: https://devopscube.com/mount-extra-disks-on-google-cloud/
4. Download netplan.io to that disk

`cd /demo-mount`

`wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netplan.io/netplan.io_0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb`

5. Unmount the Disk

`sudo umount /demo-mount`

6. Remove the Disk from the VM
7. Attach the Disk to the Affected VM
8. Mount the Disk to the Affected VM

`sudo mkdir -p /demo-mount`

9. Go to the Mounted Directory

`sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/sdb /demo-mount`

10. Install the new package

`sudo dpkg -i netplan.io_0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb`

11. Stop the VM
12. Remove the Disk
13. Start the VM